# 'SBJSON' undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: iphone, json, ios4

I am getting 'SBJSON' undeclared (first use in this function) error when i try to run the below piece of code.

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import <JSON/JSON.h>


@implementation RootViewController


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View lifecycle


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

        NSString *myRawJson=[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver/jsondata.php"]];

        if([myRawJson length]==0)
        {
            [myRawJson release];
            return;
        }

        SBJSON *parser=[[SBJSON alloc]init];

        list = [[parser objectWithString:myRawJson error:nil]copy];
        [parser release];   

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

Can anybody help please. I am using SDK 4.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used SBJsonParser instead of SBJSON and it works fine now. Maybe it has something to do with the iOS version I am on..

Answer (score 0):

It’s this line:

```
#import <JSON/JSON.h>
```

You’re trying to import [a JSON framework](http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) but you don’t have it installed.

Comment: I do have it installed. i have also tested it with NSLog(@"Parsed some JSON: %@", [@"[1,2,3,true,false,null]" JSONValue]); and everything seems to work fine. Also when i type SBJSON the editor does give me autocomplete feature for the word..